# Relationship between kafka and disruptor

Tags: apache-kafka, disruptor-pattern

I'm starting reading about kafka and found some similarities with Disruptor farmework.

Is there any relationship between kafka/Disruptor,can we consider kafka as an implementation of Disruptor?..
Can anyone please help me identifying the relation between them?

Comment: Could you add some more detail on the similarities you see? What did you want to compare them on?

Comment: Both are about finding a solution to the traditional producer/consumer pattern using queue.
Disruptor is using its "ring buffer" data structure and Kafka is using queue partitionning.
I found on github a disruptor-kafka-consumer example which explain why I'm asking about ther elation between them

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/when-disruptor-not-good-fit

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is not implement of disruptor, they are both message queue and both can process large amount data(events) in sequence. There are many difference between them, you can think the abstract designs are absolutely two ways(so each one has its advantage). Kafka is designed for big data system and distribute system, often used between different systems(easy to use and won't lost data even during power failure), disruptor is based on the cache and multi-threads so it can process data very very quickly(than kafka) but hard to deal with, so it often used inside one system.

If you have a kafka and want to accelerate consuming inside your system, you can use a disruptor to consume the kafka.

Summary:

- kafka is a "big" message queue used between systems
- disruptor is a "small" message queue(and faster) used between JVM multi-threads inside one system.